# Create directory in hadoop filesystem

Tags: shell, hadoop, hdfs, command-line-interface

I'm new to hadoop. I am trying to create a directory in hdfs but I am not able to create.

I have logged into "hduser" hence I assumed /home/hduser" pre-exists as Unix fs. So I tried to create hadoop directory using below command.

```
[hduser@Virus ~]$ hadoop fs -mkdir /home/hduser/mydata/
14/12/03 15:04:53 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
mkdir: `/home/hduser/mydata/': No such file or directory
```

After online search, i thought of it is possible that hadoop is not able to understand "/home/hduser" or as I m using hadoop2 where mkdir wont work like Unix command "madir -p" (recursively). Hence I tried to create  "/mydata" but no luck.

```
[hduser@Virus ~]$ hadoop fs -mkdir /mydata
14/12/03 15:09:26 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
mkdir: Cannot create directory /mydata. Name node is in safe mode.
```

I tried to leave the safemode but still issue persists.

```
[hduser@Virus ~]$ hdfs dfsadmin -safemode leave
14/12/03 15:09:13 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Safe mode is OFF
```

I also tried with "/user/mydata" as "/user" is the directory which hadoop took as home.

```
[hduser@Virus ~]$ hadoop fs -mkdir /user/mydata
14/12/03 15:36:20 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
mkdir: Cannot create directory /user/mydata. Name node is in safe mode.
```

Now how to debug further?

Comment: Your name node not yet left safe mode.http://unmeshasreeveni.blogspot.in/2014/04/name-node-is-in-safe-mode-how-to-leave.html

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To leave safe mode, try below command since `hadoop dfsadmin -safemode` is deprecated in newer distribution of Hadoop:

```
 hdfs dfsadmin -safemode leave
```

By default, user's `home` directory in hdfs exists with '/user/hduser' not as /home/hduser'.

If you tried to create directory directly like below then it will be created like '/user/hduser/sampleDir'.

```
hadoop fs -mkdir /path/to/be/created
```

Comment: If I try ~/foldername from /home/hduser it doesn't create  /home/hduser/foldername, 
it creates /user/hduser/foldername

As you said user's default home directory in hdfs exists with '/user/hduser' not as /home/hduser
Very helpful

Answer (score 7):

On HDFS,

```
hdfs dfs -mkdir -p /this/is/a/new/directory
```

Answer (score 6):

Create a directory /user

```
hadoop fs -mkdir /user
```

then with your user name

```
hadoop fs -mkdir /user/yourusername
```

Now try to creating directory.

Comment: Also, you can make it with one command: `hadoop fs -mkdir -p /user/ysername`;

Answer (score 2):

List your directory

```
hadoop fs -ls /
```

**Output:**

```
Found 1 items
drwxr-xr-x   - sony supergroup          0 2016-12-10 16:45 /usr
```

**create a directory**

```
hadoop fs -mkdir /app
```

created successfully and check

```
hadoop fs -ls /
```

**Output:**

```
Found 2 items
drwxr-xr-x   - sony supergroup          0 2016-12-12 04:11 /usr
drwxr-xr-x   - sony supergroup          0 2016-12-10 16:45 /app
```